# Lightning Standard List View - select specific rows

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-community, list-view

I want to Select individual/multiple rows from a Standard Lightning Lead List View on click of a button in a Lightning Page that I've configured.

What are my options ? I'm thinking using a List View Button to open a VF page that can fetch individual rows selected from my list view using StandardSetController.

Is there a way I can do this without using VF pages.

Update : Custom Visualforce List Buttons are not supported in Communities and thus I can't use them. Please suggest if there's a workaround this ?

Comment: What's the purpose of fetching the selected rows? Are you looking to fetch each record's data? Just the ids? There are many ways to do something like this, but since you're using Lightning, I would leverage customizable lightning components such as [Lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example)

Comment: I don't want to use Custom Lightning components, I want to use the standard list view and select records from it and perform actions on those records.

Comment: Interesting, I thought about using List View Mass Action, Sounded pretty good for the updates, but looks like you cant add them to list view if they have any lightning components in it.